# Генерация ссылки на Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

как сделать следующую ссылку с помощью `@Html.ActionLink`?

```
<a href="~/Home/Index">Home <span class="anyClass"> »</span></a>
```

Моя проблема состоит в `<span>...</span>`.как засунуть `<span>...</span>` в @Html.ActionLink?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink` - это генерация всего тега целиком. Если вам нужен только Url определенного action-а - используйте `@Url.Action`.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home <span class="anyClass"> »</span></a>
```